# Where to get Windows container base image to run in Docker or VirtualBox on Windows 10 Enterprise (64-bit)

Tags: docker-for-windows, windows-container

I am running Windows 10 Enterprise (64-bit) in virtual environment.
I have installed Docker and VirtualBox in it.
For my work, I need a Windows container base image (with .NET support).
I tried getting one at https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-base-os-images?tab=reviews
But, could not pull a Windows or Windows Server Core image.

Please let me know if you know how to get and use Windows container base image.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/container-base-images

Comment: _"But, could not pull a Windows or Windows Server Core image."_  Can you elaborate the problems you faced in pulling the image?

Comment: _"Windows requires the host OS version to match the container OS version. If you want to run a container based on a newer Windows build, make sure you have an equivalent host build. Otherwise, you can use Hyper-V isolation to run older containers on new host builds."_ Did you properly read this and select the proper image tag?

Comment: Now I was able to pull the image, by using the following line in my Dockerfile,     FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1909. I was using latest tag, instead.

Comment: I am posting it as an answer. Kindly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation available on [docker-hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore):

> Windows requires the host OS version to match the container OS
> version. If you want to run a container based on a newer Windows
> build, make sure you have an equivalent host build. Otherwise, you can
> use Hyper-V isolation to run older containers on new host builds.

You are probably trying to pull a non-compliant image. Check your windows version and accordingly select the proper tag to pull.

Comment: If in my Dockerfile, I have `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:latest`, how big is that image going to be?